# Could we technically decrypt a signed message using public key?

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, x509

Cos I thought we can only verify that a signature was signed by a public key. Cos otherwise everyone can decrypt the signature since public key is, well, public. This [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-browsers-verify-digital-certificates-part-1-26ee57a6e712) and [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/public-key-cryptography-and-digital-signatures-6d81a06c15c4) both seem to say yes we can decrypt.

And this image from [SO](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/56393) too -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/q28Zw.png

Comment: A signature is *signed* by a *private* key, and *verified* with a public key.  The data that is signed is typically a digest over the input data, not the input data itself, so 'decrypting' it doesn't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could we technically decrypt a signed message using public key?

A signed message does not even need to be encrypted in the first place. Instead a message signature is a cryptographic hash over the message and this hash is then signed using a signature algorithm. Such signature algorithm might be like an encryption (in case of RSA) or something else (ECDSA).

Still, the original message cannot be restored from the hash and thus also not "decrypted" from the signature. Apart from that the message is encrypted TO the recipient while the signature is done BY the sender - different keys are involved here.

> Cos otherwise everyone can decrypt the signature since public key is ...

Decrypting the signature is different from decrypting the message. As for the "decrypt" part - signature validation involves decrypting in case of RSA but  with ECDSA and others it is different.